# how to use @Requestmapping of a different project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Java project with various @RequestMapping annotations.I want to make a new project which can use this @RequestMapping,is that possible

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
If I understand your question correctly, do you want to use the data provided by a Spring application in another application?
It's not that hard, you just have to keep a few things in mind.
The applications have to run on different ports, of course both applications have to be started.

For example, App1 has a @RequestMapping @GetMapping for personal data.
The path is e.g. http://localhost:8080/persondata
In the second application, you only need to address the API endpoint if you need this data.
This can be done with RestTemplate, for example.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persondata")
class PersonDataRestController {

private final Service personService;

public PersonDataRestController(Service personService) {
    this.personService = personService;
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Collection<?>> getAllPersonData() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.allPersonData());
}

}
```

You just have to replace the Service with your PersonService or whatelse.

in the second application you can call the REST endpoint with RestTemplate for example

```
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    try{
        ResponseEntity<ArrayList<?>> response = template.exchange("http://localhost:8080/persondata", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<?>>() {});
```

In terms of the specific application, you may need a DTO object.

For this topic i can suggest you [this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_building_restful_web_services.htm)

I hope I could answer your question